MemoryError in creating large numpy array
My objective is to plot a histogram given values and counts. hist only takes an array of data as input. I have tried to recreat data using np.repeat, but this gives MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.9 GiB for an array with shape (2138500000,) and data type float64.
Wanted to know if there is a smarter way of doing this.
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

values = [ 1, 2, 2.5, 4, 5, 5.75, 6.5]
counts = [10**8, 10**9, 1.5*10**7, 1.25*10**7, 10**6, 10**7,10**9]

data_recreated = np.repeat(values, counts)

f1, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.hist(data_recreated, bins=5)


I have no idea what the goal is, since you have not really specified it. Is the goal to create an array with over a billion copies of the array values?

Same here not sure what is ideal use case of using repeat here? Are you trying to say  you want to represent a dataset where: The value 1 appears 100 million times
The value 2 appears 1 billion times and so on in orginal array?

"The value 1 appears 100 million times The value 2 appears 1 billion times"- this is not the objective. Objective is to plot the histogram, but in order to do that I have to recreate the data from values and frequency.

"Objective is to plot the histogram, but in order to do that I have to recreate the data" No. See my answer below.

The vertical bars in the accepted answer are not centered about the discrete values in the values list

@gboffi they don't have to be. In a histogram the nearby values are pooled together and their cumulative count is plotted as the bar height. The width of bars cover the range of (x-)values.

As i mentioned in comments not sure what is your ideal use cases for using repeat here? Are you trying to say you want to represent a dataset where: The value 1 appears 100 million times The value 2 appears 1 billion times and so on in orginal array?...
If so then Instead of creating the full array, we can achieve the same statistical visualization using weights.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


values = [1, 2, 2.5, 4, 5, 5.75, 6.5]
counts = [10**8, 10**9, 1.5*10**7, 1.25*10**7, 10**6, 10**7, 10**9]


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))


plt.hist(values, bins=5, weights=counts, edgecolor='black')


plt.title('Histogram of Values')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')


plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

# Add grid for better readability
plt.grid(True, alpha=0.3)


plt.show()

which results

To verify
counts_hist, bin_edges, _ = plt.hist(values, bins=5, weights=counts)
print("\nBin edges:", bin_edges)
print("Counts in each bin:", counts_hist)

Bin edges: [1.  2.1 3.2 4.3 5.4 6.5]
Counts in each bin: [1.10e+09 1.50e+07 1.25e+07 1.00e+06 1.01e+09]

which is
1.10 billion
15 million
12.5 million
1 million
1.01 billion

so a result
When you use plt.hist(values, bins=5, weights=counts) it:
Places each value in its appropriate bin Instead of counting 1 for each value, it adds the weight for that value and Creates bars with heights equal to the sum of weights in each bin ultimately result is identical

This doesn't appear to be quite right; why does the first bar have a value of 1.1e9? Where has the 1e8 gone that was the first count?

Also why are the bars all the same width, when values is not uniform?

@tmdavison (1) the first bar values - 10**8 + 10**9 (2) the bars have to be of the same width, the values translates to height of the bar


You needn't plt.hist, that first counts the elements in an array and later draws the bars — you already have the counts, hence you can directly draw the bars using plt.bar.
Because the range of y data is 1:1000 I decided to plot vs a logarithmic scale, please remove plt.semilogy() if you prefer/are required a linear scale.
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

values = np.array([ 1, 2, 2.5, 4, 5, 5.75, 6.5])
counts = np.array([1E8, 1E9, 1.5E7, 1.25E7, 1E6, 1E7, 1E9])

bars = plt.bar(values, counts, width=0.4)
plt.semilogy()
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.xticks(values)
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()

